# Entity framework and VARBINARY

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005, entity-framework

I’m using the .NET entity framework and I’ve got one entity containing a varbinary. Is there an easy way to get the size of the varbinary in the codebehind, efter it’s been retrieved from the database?

I’m thinking there might be some way to get the size directly from the entity, something like entity.Context.Size – or do one need to handle it differently?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A `varbinary` translates to a `byte[]` field in Entity Framework, which means you can check the **Length** property of the array:

```
int fieldSize = entity.MyVarBinaryField.Length;
```

As mentioned by [tster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5409481/137471): In a LINQ to Entities query, you can call the [DataLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.datalength.aspx) method of the [SqlFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466188.aspx) class, which will translate into a [DATALENGTH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173486.aspx) function call in the generated SQL statement. This only works with SQL Server and Entity Framework 4 or later:

```
int? fieldSize = repository.Entity
  .Select(e => SqlFunctions.DataLength(e.MyVarBinaryField)).Single();
```

Comment: Just a little heads up, this does not work inside a query (as of EF 4.0). It gives the error message: The LINQ expression node type 'ArrayLength' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.

Comment: I'm not sure if it even worked inside a query in EF 1. Marcus L. explicitly asked how to get the size of the varbinary after it's has been retrieved from the database, in which case the above works just fine. If only the size is needed, and not the binary data itself, I would recommend either storing the size in a seperate field, or running a seperate query using the DATALENGTH function, as Marcus ended up doing. In any case, thanks for the heads up :)

Comment: I updated the answer to include an example of retrieving the data length in a LINQ to Entities query (EF 4 only)

Answer (score 11):

I know this question is old, but EF now supports this by using `SqlFunctions.DataLength()`

Comment: I saw that in MSDN but unsure how to implement.  Could you give an example?

Comment: Nevermind, I was just looking in the wrong namespace.  Note that the fully qualified name is `System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions.DataLength()`

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by running another query, getting the DATALENGTH() of the cell. Not the smoothest way but it works.

I'm still interested in hearing if anyone can come up with an answer for this though.