# Custom Fields for IdentityUser

Tags: asp.net-identity-2

I am trying to add custom fields for my IdentityUser. I have been through the documentation and also several articles that I've found online. I was able to figure out how to add custom fields, but I'm not sure how to set constraints on them. None of the articles I've found have covered this topic.

```
    // You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your ApplicationUser class, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public DateTime RegistrationDate { get; set; }

    public string IPAddress { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

My code example is above. I have added 2 fields. RegistrationDate and IPAddress. I've used PowerShell to create the migrations and update the database.

My questions are this:

1. How do I set a default value for RegistrationDate? I wanted it to be SQL Now(). I can make the change in the database after the migration, but that gets my code and database out of sync.
2. On IPAddress, I want to have the maximum size be 39 characters. When I update the database, the field is created as NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL. I want it to be NVARCHAR(39) NOT NULL. I can't see anyway to do that in the IdentityUser.
3. Lastly, what if I wanted to store the IPAddress as VARBINARY or BINARY? That's not even a data type that C# will accept.

I am able to go into the migration files and make some changes after creating the migration, but those changes are not reflected in the database. If I try to re-run Update-database from PowerShell, I get an error saying that there are no changes to update.

On top of that. I don't know if I should be manually updating the migration files, since they are generated code.

```
    public partial class IPAddress : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn("dbo.AspNetUsers", "IPAddress", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 39));
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropColumn("dbo.AspNetUsers", "IPAddress");
    }
}
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and version 4.6.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) To have a default date on your `RegistrationDate` you need to create a default constructor of `ApplicationUser` that sets your date to be whatever you need:

```
public ApplicationUser()
{
    RegistrationDate = DateTime.Now();
}
```

2) To change the size of the field you need to apply `[MaxLength(39)]` attribute on your `IPAddress` field:

```
 [MaxLength(39)]
 public string IPAddress { get; set; }
```

3) To get `BINARY` you need to use `byte[]` type in C#. (ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1158670/809357)

4) You should not change the scripts for migrations manually - migrations contain XML snapshot of the database and keeps that snapshot in the `__MigrationsHistory` table. So if you change the migration script, the snapshot will not be re-generated and EF won't pick up your changes.

When you change your data model you either create a new migration via `add-migration NewMigrationName` or rollback your DB to a previous migration state via `update-database -Target PreviousMigrationName` and then re-generate existing migration via `add-migration ExistingMigrationName -Force` and then do `Update-database`

Comment: Awesome! That appears to have easily fixed everything. Since I already messed up the migrations, I did a rollback to the InitialCreate migration which appeared to completely undo everything I did manually. Then I deleted the migration cs file that I changed manually, which I wasn't using anymore. I made the changes to the fields in ApplicationUser and then added a new migration and it correctly set the constraints in the database this time. Did I do the process correctly? If so, this was really easy to do. Identity and EntityFramework are amazing!

Comment: Sounds like you've done it fine and correctly. Glad it works for you!