# Entity Framework 6 Code First VarBinary Length in mapping or computed column

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, code-first, ef-fluent-api

I see it is possible to use a query to find a length of a varbinary field in a query.

[Entity framework and VARBINARY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605790/entity-framework-and-varbinary)

But can you map a FileSize property to get the size of a varbinary in the Fluent API without having to write queries?

I want to be able to store some file information in SQL Server.  This data is a filename, file contents.  This has a definition in the data model as follows:

```
public class FileData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Filename { get; set; }

    public byte[] Contents { get; set; }
}
```

Typically, I want to know the size of the contents when I retrieve FileData.  If I added an int property FileSize to FileData, can you map this property to compute the size?

I can configure this in SQL:

[image: SQL Computed Length Field]

And when I insert into the table it gives me the correct size.

However, if I generate my data model/DbContext using VS2015 -> Add New Item... -> ADO.NET Entity Data Model, my FileData POCO only has an annotation with DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed) on the FileSize property.  Nothing else reflects the len(Contents) formula I added.

Is it possible to configure this sort of computed column using EF6 Code First?

Comment: Do you need to know the file size BEFORE you retrieve the record?  Because after you get the object, a `Contents.Length` would get you the size without having to maintain it in a secondary field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create computed columns in entity framework code first. The way you're doing it is correct, you just put the `DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)` attribute on the property, `Entity Framework` won't try to create the column then for you, and you create the column manually. A good idea is to make the property private set, since you won't ever need to manually modify it:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
public int? FileSize {get; private set;}
```